# Python script not importing module while running through PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, import, module

I have a PHP script which calls for a Python script, that Python script imports a library, runs some code and returns the result. The problem is that if I run the script directly from the shell (I'm using linux) it works perfectly, but if I open the PHP file in the browser I get an error saying:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Traceback (most recent call last):
    [1] =>   File "readReplays.py", line 3, in 
    [2] =>     import sc2reader
    [3] => ImportError: No module named sc2reader
)
```

I would really appreciate help because I've been having problems with this kinds of stuff for over 17 hours :P

Comment: check your python's `sys.path` when called from php.

Comment: As flied onion said - check python's sys.path when called from php and directly in shell - and compare it to find out what paths you have to add manually.

Comment: I've got this in my python script: `sys.path.insert(1,'$HOME/lib/python2.6/site-packages/');`. The path is the same as PYTHONPATH

Comment: Your $HOME is not the same as PHP's $HOME

Comment: Oooh, I just outputed the sys.path from shell and in the script, it is missing quite a few links.

Answer (score 0):

The case is for apche to find the correct path to python you should mention it in its conf file.
For example if u have redhat linux 
you should add
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin

to /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd.conf

PYTHONPATH IS PATH TO YOUR PYTHON EXECUTABLE which you can find by command 
which python

Then it will work